# How can I turn off commands appearing in chat on a Pocket Edition Realm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any way for me to turn off commands on a Minecraft Pocket Edition realm?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to enable cheats on your world via the world options before you join the world, once you do that you'll have the permissions to type commands in chat.